# Why is PostgreSQL remembering my previous instalations?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

Recently I installed PostgreSQL 10.4, but it was losing connection all the time. I uninstalled it, removed the data folder and installed version 9.6, which didn't help, so I uninstalled it as well and removed the data folder. I installed 10.4 again hoping that it will work well this time.

When I opened pgAdmin it showed as if version 9.6 was still installed apart form the 10.4 (which should be there). I tried creating a user in it (to see if it really works) and it created it successfully, but after further investigation I realized that it created the same user in the 10.4 installation. It must have been the same installation, but pgAdmin saw it as two separate ones. I deleted both installations form pgAdmin and reinstalled version 10.4.

Everything works fine now, but I still wanted to ask what might have caused this issue? Can it cause problems for my existing db in the future?

Comment: I answered the same question here regarding pgAdmin on MacOS https://stackoverflow.com/a/74555965/1045085.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not "PostgreSQL" that remembered the installation. It's pgAdmin where you simply didn't delete the configured connection. Connection information is something specific to the SQL client, not the database server.

The existing [connection definition](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/3.x/connecting.html) uses the same hostname, port and apparently password that was valid for a running 9.6 server or the new Postgres 10 server. The name of that "server" is something that is specified in pgAdmin and has nothing to do with the actual Postgres installation. You could have named the  "9.6 Server" connection "Connect to some nice DBMS" instead.

That information is not stored together with the PostgreSQL installation, but in your user profile.