# How do I save changes in pgAdmin 4

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I am a complete beginner with postgreSQL. There are 2 servers and I want to delete one. I click "remove server" but when I exit the program I have no way to save this change and on reopening the program the second server is back. This seems incredibly simple but I cannot find any obvious way to save this change. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you right click on the server, there should be an option "properties".  In the comments, it might say that is an "auto-detected" server that was installed.  If it says that, I don't believe that you will be able to delete it from this menu.  If it doesn't have the comment, then you should be able to disconnect from the server and then remove it.  I have had the same issue and sometimes it works for me and sometimes it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running pgAdmin 4 on MacOS. I had the same problem with old versions of Postgres. For example, for Postgres 10, I had deleted the /Library/PostgresSQL/10 directory and removed "PostgresSQL 10" from pgAdmin 4, but "PostgresSQL 10" reappears when I open pgAdmin 4 again.

To permanently remove "PostgresSQL 10" from pgAdmin 4, I had to do the following:

1. Download and install the Postgres 10 installer from https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads.
2. Run `open /Library/PostgreSQL/10/uninstall-postgresql.app` on a terminal.
3. Open pgAdmin 4 and remove "PostgresSQL 10" again.

Then "PostgresSQL 10" is permanently removed from pgAdmin 4.

Repeat these steps for other Postgres versions that you have in pgAdmin 4 that you want to remove.